# How do I move an object based on its rotation in Processing? (Local axis)

Tags: java, rotation, processing, translate

So i'm trying to make a car game in processing, where the car moves just in his local y axis, and it turns by rotating. But i cant figure out how to make it move on the local y axis once it has rotated, that is the part where i need help. I post the code in Processing:

```
class CarClass{
  float speed, x, y, steering, w;
  CarClass(){
    speed = 5;
    x = width/2;
    y = height/2;
    steering = radians(0);
    w = 5;
  }

  void display(){
    translate(x, y);
    rotate(steering);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(0, 0, 40, 82);   
  }

  void up(){
    y -= speed;
  }
  void down(){
    y += speed;
  }
  void left(){
    steering -= radians(w);
  }
  void right(){
    steering += radians(w);
  }  
}

void movement(){
  if(keyPressed) {
    if (keyCode == UP) {
      car.up();
    }
    if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      car.down();
    }
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      car.left();
    } 
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      car.right();
    }
  }
}

CarClass car;


void setup(){
  size(854,480);
  car = new CarClass();
}

void draw(){
  background(10,10,10);
  car.display();
  movement();
}
```

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/36046/how-do-i-make-an-entity-move-in-a-direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the car in the direction, which is defined by the `steering` angle.

In the window, the x axis points to the left and the y points upwards. The `steering` angle is measured clockwise from the upwards direction.
The direction vector can be get by the trigonometric functions [`sin`](https://processing.org/reference/sin_.html) and [`cos`](https://processing.org/reference/cos_.html) and is:

`v = (sin(steering), -cos(steering))`

Use this vector to manipulate the position (`x`, `y`) of the car:

```java
class CarClass {

    // [...]

    void up(){
        x += sin(steering) * speed;
        y -= cos(steering) * speed;
    }
    void down(){
        x -= sin(steering) * speed;
        y += cos(steering) * speed;
    }

    // [...]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You are literally god, even though I guess it wasn't difficult for u